# What's faster? Load file lines into list Or process fileobject line by line in for loop? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, zip

Writing code that will parse zipped log files (typically no bigger than 500KB) and load some contents of those files into a DB. **Sample of log file:**

```
SITE_COUNT: 11
PRB_CARD: 108
PRB_FACILITY: LEHI
PROCESS_ID: 88AFX
TEMP: 0
DATA_SET_ID: _P9kTbjdptOyonKO_
START_DATETIME: 05/01/2020 03:06:24
LOT: 0522072.0
.
.
.
+ 1 1588323984 1NA:0NN
{
Head(1) Site(0) (X,Y)=(-4,16)
VALID_COUNT 712

*Z
SITE:PARAM_SITE:N3P3
SITE:PROCESS_DURATION:81
1000:1665.67:VALID
.
.
1007:12.0638:VALID
1011:27.728:VALID
.
.
NUM_REGISTERS 712
NUM_VALID 6787
NUM_TESTED 6787
}
FINISH_ETIME: 1588324881
```

Each file ends with FINISH_ETIME. Again this is a very very small sample of the log files.

Anways, for the db, I need the "header" info which is typically in the first 50 lines of the log file. And then I need the information under the Head(1) Site(0). I need all those numbers in front of the VALID text.

To this regard, I opened the file under the zip module and used a forloop to process the file object line by line and use if statments to get the information I need.

My mentor thinks this is wasteful as I am running through the entire file and checking each line as I go through the file for information regardless if I have already gotten the info or not. So even though I already have 'Process_ID', I still check for it as each new line comes in:

```
for odfslogp_obj in logstocrunch_Pobjs_set:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(odfslogp_obj, mode='r') as z:
        for name in z.namelist():
            with z.open(name) as etest_zip:
                for line in etest_zip:
                    if b"PROCESS_ID" in line:
                        pattern = re.compile(rb"(\S*F[IR]P)")
                        match = pattern.search(line)
                        if match:
                        #print(match)
                            #print(match.group(1).decode())
                            file_meta_dict["filetype"] = match.group(1).decode()
                            print(file_meta_dict["filetype"])
```

Instead he suggests I read the zip file and put all the lines into a list usign list comprehension

Then use several list comprehension lists to narrow down to sections of the file where I need information. So for the header sections (the first 50)  lines. I'd just need a list comprehension list that gets the first 50 lines and then iterate through that list to feed my header information

This method introduces a bunch of lists and comprehensions.

I am wondering if it is worth rewriting my code to do this as he says he thinks it would be faster instead of using the for loop that looks through each line.

Keep in mind, I also need to check relevant data in each line I need to make sure it meets certain criteria for error flagging.

Comment: Surely it would only be worth rewriting if the performance matters so much to make it worth it, which you don’t address in your question - there’s no ‘it’s too slow!’ Personally I find list comprehensions are so much harder to debug than for loops that I prefer to avoid them until I have the logic down pat.

Comment: it would be better if you write down (may be make a process diagram) to see how you are processing the data and how the mentor is trying to say, as per your code you are first reading entire thing and then checking conditions, if you can check condition at same time as of reading then it would help you to optimize your code and process it linear time compare to the other solution

Comment: @barny I haven't gone too deep into the code but of course I need to redo key logic which will take time. Mainly because I also need to understand his method. That was what I brought up. Ultimately I want to write the most modular efficient code I can write, We do have a deadline of next week

Comment: ‘Deadline of next week’: better get on with getting something to work, unless your mentor is hinting that you will also be assessed in some unspecified way on performance/style/approach in which case you’d better get on with rewriting.

Comment: @sahasrara62 But I am not reading the entire thing then checkign the conditions. I am checking the codiitions as I read each line. Unless I don't understand my own logic. 

His issue is that my code is not as modular as it can be because he wanted me to load headers from a config file. And also that the if statements check every line in the file as I go through the file. He thinks this is not ideal and that it shoudl only check a small sub section

Comment: You can break out of the loop as soon as you’ve got everything you need - no reason to always read the whole file. OTOH reading a bunch of lines at once should be more efficient than one at a time. Go figure. Unless you write both you won’t know which is “faster”

Comment: Eh unforunately I need a lot of header information so it wouldn't be good to break out of loop once I ecounter my first if condition. So you think going through a list that contains only a sub section of the file would be faster? Despite the fact that I would be using multiple lists for different parts of the file? @barny

Comment: ‘Would be faster?’ Who knows. Depends if reading the whole file in one slurp is faster than only reading enough one line at a time. You should be able to try that out. IMO there’s no single answer without sight of all your data. Even then there might not be. You could write some code and make some measurements. Or just get on and do something rather than asking for speculative advice/reassurance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about speed, but I will answer about design. The deadline is missed anyway, and there are some many parameters (list comprehension vs regular loop, load file at once or read it line by line, ...) that nobody could give a definite answer without benchmarks.

It seems you need a [finite-state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). The idea is simple: the way you handle a line depends on the current state. This is exactly what your mentor said when he made this remark:

> I am running through the entire file and checking each line as I go through the file for information regardless if I have already gotten the info or not.

(I suspect that the list comprehension suggestion was not the most important part of his remarks.)

Imagine you have three states: `header_not_parsed`, `header_parsed`, `head_1_site_0_found`. You start in the state `header_not_parsed` and check for `PROCESS_ID`, `DATA_SET_ID`, .... When the header parsing is complete, you move to `header_parsed` state and only look for `Head(1) Site(0)...`. When this line has been found, you move to `head_1_site_0_found` and store all the `m:n:VALID` numbers. When the right `}` is found, you leave.

The advantage is obvious: the process of the line matches the state, hence it is simpler *and faster* than processing a line without knowing the state.

Here is a quick and dirty proof of concept that uses the abilty of Python to change a function during the execution of the program:

```
class Parser:
    def parse(self, f):
        self._data = {}
        self._parse_line = self._parse_header_line
        for line in f:
            if not self._parse_line(line): # parse_line returns False if you have to leave the loop
                break
        return self._data

    def _parse_header_line(self, line):
        if line.startswith("+"): # end of header
            self._parse_line = self._parse_after_header_line # next state
        try:
            k, v = map(str.strip, line.split(":"))
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            self._data[k] = v
        return True

    def _parse_after_header_line(self, line):
        if line.startswith("Head(1) Site(0)"): # begin of head_1_site_0
            self._parse_line = self._parse_head_1_site_0_line # next state
        return True

    def _parse_head_1_site_0_line(self, line):
        if line.startswith("}"): # end of the interesting part of the log
            self._parse_line = self._leave_loop # next state

        *ks, v = map(str.strip, line.split(":"))
        if v == "VALID":
            self._data.setdefault("VALID", []).append(ks)
        return True

    def _leave_loop(self, line):
        return False # return false to break
```

A test with your sample:

```
import io

f = io.StringIO("""SITE_COUNT: 11
PRB_CARD: 108
PRB_FACILITY: LEHI
PROCESS_ID: 88AFX
TEMP: 0
DATA_SET_ID: _P9kTbjdptOyonKO_
START_DATETIME: 05/01/2020 03:06:24
LOT: 0522072.0
.
.
.
+ 1 1588323984 1NA:0NN
{
Head(1) Site(0) (X,Y)=(-4,16)
VALID_COUNT 712

*Z
SITE:PARAM_SITE:N3P3
SITE:PROCESS_DURATION:81
1000:1665.67:VALID
.
.
1007:12.0638:VALID
1011:27.728:VALID
.
.
NUM_REGISTERS 712
NUM_VALID 6787
NUM_TESTED 6787
}
FINISH_ETIME: 1588324881""")

print(Parser().parse(f))
```

Output:

```
{'SITE_COUNT': '11', 'PRB_CARD': '108', 'PRB_FACILITY': 'LEHI', 'PROCESS_ID': '88AFX', 'TEMP': '0', 'DATA_SET_ID': '_P9kTbjdptOyonKO_', 'LOT': '0522072.0', '+ 1 1588323984 1NA': '0NN', 'VALID': [['1000', '1665.67'], ['1007', '12.0638'], ['1011', '27.728']]}
```

Of course, if the finite state machine begins to be complex, you can switch to the [State pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) that is more robust than this example.